# what is the default access modifier for controls created on .aspx page. Private or something else?

Tags: asp.net

What is the default access modifier for controls created on .aspx page. Private or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its 'protected'.

N

Comment: hi, im sure its projected. as @Greg said, if you open the designer for the pages you can see the declarations.

Comment: it is protected due to inheritence between code behind and the aspx.cs file

Comment: Yes, thats correct. If you dont want it to be inherited you can make it private or sealed

Answer (score 1):

`protected`

If you open the MyPage.aspx.designer.cs (or MyPage.aspx.designer.vb) you can see the declarations for the controls.

Comment: Hmm, I guess for website projects / different version of visual studio it might be different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the controls on the aspx as considered protected by default and any methods in the code behind (.aspx.cs or aspx.vb) are private by default.  You can expose those controls by adding a public page property if you need to access it.